# Variable usage in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've some issue with a stored procedure on a MySQL 5.6.36:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `test_schema`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `count_requests`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE count_requests()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE tablename_tmp VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE counter_tmp INT;
    DECLARE counter INT;
    DECLARE v_finished INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='test_schema' limit 10;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

    OPEN v_cur;
        get_flagged: LOOP
            FETCH v_cur INTO tablename_tmp;
            IF v_finished = 1 THEN
                LEAVE get_flagged;
            END IF;
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counter_tmp FROM tablename_tmp WHERE data_richiesta > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-21600);
            SET counter=counter+counter_tmp;
        END LOOP get_flagged;
        CLOSE v_cur;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The targets, in order, are:

- extract a list of tables from a specific schema;
- counting the records matching a WHERE clause;
- use the previous count result to increment a variable;

The trouble comes when I try to call it because, for some reason, the SELECT COUNT statement doesn't use "tablename_tmp" as variable, but as string. So:

```
mysql> call count_requests;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test_schema.tablename_tmp' doesn't exist
```

Now, the stored procedure (logically speaking) should works beacause if I remove the SELECT COUNT to use a simple

SELECT CONCAT ('Tab name: ', tablename_tmp)

I get the expected result:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('Tab name: ', tablename_tmp) |
+-------------------------------------+
| Tab name: tab_10001                 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)

+-------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('Tab name: ', tablename_tmp) |
+-------------------------------------+
| Tab name: tab_10002                 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)

+-------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('Tab name: ', tablename_tmp) |
+-------------------------------------+
| Tab name: tab_10003                 |
+-------------------------------------+
```

I did some experiments, but without serious results and now I don't now how to proceed.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advcance.

Comment: Variable cannot be used as tablename - it is a literal. Use prepared statement.

Comment: It works! Thanks you!